# Set WSL sudo password to my Windows password

Tags: windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux

My Windows password changes every 90 days (corporate security requirements). I have Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) enabled and use it regularly - my `sudo` password is statically set and different than my Windows password. Is it possible to have my password just reflect what my Windows password is?

Comment: There is no synchronize between Windows And WSL user password. You've to do it manually. But it is good (from security view) if your both passwords are different.